"años luces" vs. "años luz"
Hola ~ ¿Por qué no es "años luces" sino "años luz"? ¡Muchas gracias!
"Para medir la distancia de la mayoría de los cuerpos del espacio usamos los años luz. Un año luz es la distancia que la luz recorre en un año terrestre. Un año luz equivale aproximadamente a 9 billones de kilómetros (cerca de 6 billones de millas). ¡Es decir un 9 con 12 ceros a la derecha!"

Como dice esta página:

Según indica la gramática académica, los plurales de expresiones como año luz, ciudad dormitorio o mueble bar son, respectivamente, años luz, ciudades dormitorio o muebles bar; esto es, con marca de plural solo en el primero de los sustantivos.

El segundo sustantivo califica al primero, que en su carácter de núcleo nominal lleva la marca de número.
Adicionalmente, leemos en esta otra página que existen casos en que el sustantivo está compuesto por dos sustantivos que se encuentran en el mismo nivel semántico, en cuyo caso se pueden o deben pluralizar ambos. Todo depende de la relación semántica que haya.
En la frase "cien años luz", claramente estamos hablando de los años, de la misma forma que hablamos de "mariposas" en "mil mariposas monarca". Los años no son luces y la mariposas no non monarcas, de ahí que no se usa el plural en el segundo sustantivo.
En cambio, en compuestos como "ciudades estados" (que puede escribirse con guion o sin él) o "perros pastores", las ciudades son estados y los perros son pastores, de ahí que se puede pluralizar también el segundo sustantivo.

¡Muchísimas gracias!

El término año luz es la distancia que recorre la luz en un año.
De esta forma el sujeto es la luz y carece de sentido hablar de luces a la hora de determinar esta medida de distancia. A pesar de ser una medida de distancia se define a partir de los años que tardaría la luz en recorrerla, por eso se pone en plural el número de años.
